# Building a speech recognition application using speech_recognition in python 27

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx

When i run the program it tells me that ensure pocketsphinx is installed correctly but when I pip install pocketsphinx it says; error:command 'swig.exe' failed: no such file or directory . Please help!..Am using windows 8.1 with Python 2.7.11

Comment: Well, what steps did you take to ensure pocketsphinx is installed?

Comment: i installed speech_recognition from python PyPI but sphinxs does not work  so i tried pip install pocketsphinx but still no luck

Comment: Pip and pypi are the same thing, as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Swig is one of the [dependencies](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python#dependencies) you need to install first to be able to compile pocketsphinx, as pocketsphinx doesn't provide any precompiled versions.

If you don't want to compile it yourself, you can try a unofficial pre-built version from here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pocketsphinx